# How to show full images instead of partial images for square images

Tags: html, css

In my grid layout, each item has a square image. I'd like each square image to show the *full* image that I upload. Right now, it's showing only a partial image (see below).
[image]

All images that I upload are square-shaped btw. Struggling here, help would be much appreciated.

```
.grid {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
grid-row-gap: 80px;
grid-column-gap: 50px;
justify-content: start; 
}


  .grid .photo {
  width: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  }

.grid .photo:after {
content: "";
display: block;
padding-bottom: 100%;
}

<div class="grid">
<article> 
<a href="#">
<div class="photo" style="background-image: url(img/example1.jpg);"></div>
<div class="text">
<h3>Title</h3>
<p>This is a dummy text to show an example</p>
</div>
</a>
</article> 

<article> 
<a href="#">
<div class="photo" style="background-image: url(img/example2.jpg);"></div>
<div class="text">
<h3>Title</h3>
<p>This is a dummy text to show an example</p>
</div>
</a>
</article> 

<article> 
<a href="#">
<div class="photo" style="background-image: url(img/example3.jpg);"></div>
<div class="text">
<h3>Title</h3>
<p>This is a dummy text to show an example</p>
</div>
</a>
</article>
```

Comment: what about `background-size: 100%` ?

Comment: thanks but it didn't work :(

Comment: Is it working for you here? https://jsbin.com/bitojugili/edit?html,css,output

Comment: sorry not sure how the images are supposed to work there, but it didn't work when I tried background-size: 100%  on my code :/ thanks though

Comment: On the link I provided, your code is working all right, by itself, showing square images in your containers.

Comment: I see. What could possibly have gone wrong with my version then...?

Comment: I'm still wondering.. What size are your images exactly?

Comment: the ones I uploaded are 600px by 600px

Comment: For some reason, it's working now (my original code)!  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `background-size` on the `.photo` class to either `cover` or `contain` could work. Likewise, the `object-fit` property might work...try a few of the values.

Personally though, I never really set the background image of an element, unless it is to be a full page background. I prefer to create an image within a div, then you can set the `width/height/min-width/min-height/max-height/max-width` properties accordingly

Comment: you should set width and height for your .photo class